# Animating negative y origin from view controller breaks constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have 2 view controllers, lets call them `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB` setup in a storyboard with autolayout. I want to animate a slide up/down animation between the 2 view controllers.

When started `ViewControllerA` is visible on screen. When an action is triggered I want `ViewControllerB` to slide down, so it's `view.origin.y` has a negative (-480) value at start and at end of animation it's `view.origin.y` is 0.

However when doing this animation Xcode nags about `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.`

If want to animate going back from `ViewControllerB` to `ViewControllerA` with a slide up animation then `ViewControllerA`s `view.origin.y` is a positive value (480) at start and at end of animation it's `view.origin.y` is 0 and Xcode does not nag anything about constraints.

Is there something special I need to take into consideration when animating from a negative y value?

Answer (score 1):

Animate your constraints instead of the view's frame. Changing a view's frame while using auto layout can produce unexpected results and you should always consider it a no go. To animate a constraint all you need to do is call:

```
constraint.constant += 200 // where constraint is NSLayoutConstraint
view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) { () -> Void in
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: In this case I'm animating 2 view controllers not some subview of `view`. And I'm using `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`. I think your suggestion more applies to when animating subviews of a view controller's `view`.

Comment: I see, fair point. Just to be sure, you might want to print out the view's constraint before animation to make sure that you're not creating an unexpected clash. Are you using an animated transition delegate?

Comment: Yes I'm using animated transition delegate. Like I wrote, animation works fine but not when y origin is negative which is strange.